# How to do multiple tasks at once?

Tags: java

How could I make this download 2 to 3 files at once and when 1 finishes it picks up another? Right now it does what it needs to do, but it takes a while if you're downloading like 30 videos at once, so I want it to download 2 or 3 at a time.

```
try {
            URL url;
            byte[] buf;
            int byteRead, byteWritten = 0;
            url = new URL(getFinalLocation(fAddress));;
            outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationDir + "\\" + localFileName));

            uCon = url.openConnection();
            is = uCon.getInputStream();
            buf = new byte[size];
            while ((byteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buf, 0, byteRead);
                byteWritten += byteRead;
            }
            System.out.println("Downloaded Successfully.");
            //System.out.println("File name:\"" + localFileName + "\"\nNo ofbytes :" + byteWritten);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try threads - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add that code to a class that implements `Runnable`. The code would go in the method `run()`. (You need to implement that method per the runnable interface.)

You then create new threads and start them passing your runnable.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new RunnableClass());
thread.start();
```

You'll need to implement some logic for passing the `fAddress` String to the `RunnableClass`. (Via the constructor, or a method that gets called before `thread.start()`.)

Does this help you get started?

**EDIT - Added example**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable("http://someaddress"));
        thread1.start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable("http://otheraddress"));
        thread2.start();

    }

    public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        String address;

        public MyRunnable(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // My code here that can access address
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think so, I'll look into the documents at this to see what's going on, but yeah it gives me some direction

Comment: @J.Doe, I've added an example to further illustrate how to do this.

Comment: Thanks that really helps

Comment: Let's say I had a while loop in main checking if each thread was running would this work? Does the main method continue to run while the threads are going?

Comment: Awesome that's exactly what I need your amazing!